# carousel angular2 not loading images from local disk

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to add a carouel component to my page using images from local disk

```
<carousel>
<slide>
    <img src="assets/images/11.png" alt="First slide">
</slide>
<slide>
    <img src="assets/images/22.png" alt="Second slide">
</slide>
<slide>
    <img src="assets/images/33.png" alt="Third slide">
</slide>
```

I am sure of the images path, no problem in this side. when page is loaded, images are not showing. 
Instead if I use the same code with images from the web, everything loads correctly

```
<carousel>
    <slide>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1" alt="First slide">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/2" alt="Second slide">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/3" alt="Third slide">
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eofzb.png)

If I open URL http://localhost:49863/app/app.component.html, the images are loading correctly, but the page design is of course not correct

Comment: Try using `[src]`

Comment: please share the folder structure. is your **html** file and **assets** folder are in same directory level ?

Comment: Can you also check the network tab of your browser developer tool and check whether the images are loaded

Comment: I updated my question with a picture of my project structure. when inspecting the web page with chrome, it shows no errors